# Method that returns Void which also throws causes annoying warning in editor

Tags: error-handling, swift2, do-catch

I use this method:

```
public func setCategory(category: String, withOptions options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions) throws
```

It's an AVAudioSession method and as you can see it doesnt return anything but it should throw and error.

I do like this:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)
```

This gives me an annoying warning:

> Result of 'try?' is unused

I tried to set it into a variable and put it into a do-catch but still the same warning...

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `?` with `!` and it will look like:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)
```

And your warning will gone.

**UPDATE:**

This won't crash:

```
_ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)
```

Comment: But if it fails wont it crash then? Sorry havent dug into the new Error Handling too much

Comment: Many thanks, hipefully Apple will do something smart with this case where a void can throw.

Comment: happy to help you..:)

Comment: Thank you! This helped too even for the newest version as of October 29.